# Style properties in XML for DialogFragment is not applied

Tags: android

I want to create a style for my `DialogFragments` with these properties but they are never applied to my `DialogFragments`.

The size never change to `100dp`. As you can see, I have used both `android:width`and `layout_width`but neither of these do anything.

The padding is not applied too.

The background `R.drawable.popup_rounded_frame` is just a `shape` of an rectangle with rounded corners.

It almost work, but the background is also applied to my other `RelativeLayouts'` backgrounds in my layout. But It dosen't work as this: `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.popup_rounded_frame);` that actually remove the current background and replaced it with the one you want.

This `<item name="android:background">@drawable/popup_rounded_frame</item>` only sets the background atop of the current!

**Style for my DialogFragment**

```
<style name="ArionDialogFragment" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

    <item name="android:width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">100dp</item>

    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>


    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/popup_rounded_frame</item>

</style>
```

**This is how my DialogFragment is started**

```
  popuptest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PopUP popUP = new PopUP();
            popUP.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.ArionDialogFragment);
            popUP.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"d");

        }
    });
```

**This is the `PopUp` that extends DialogFragment**

```
public class PopUP extends DialogFragment {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connectsensor,container,false);


    return v;
}
```

This is how it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iy5b5t8ax293oo/Screenshot_20160913-123922.png?dl=0

Comment: Try you to put the `setStyle(...)` code inside the `onCreate()` method in the PopUP class. `@Override public void onCreate(...) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.ArionDialogFragment);
  }`

Comment: @nicopasso the background is applied but not the width/height

Comment: @nicopasso I have make all these proporties in the class in the PopUP then everything works

Answer (score 0):

I think you do in in a wrong way. You need to apply the style when you create your dialog. Something like this:

```
public static class AwesomeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static AwesomeDialogFragment newInstance() {
        AwesomeDialogFragment f = new AwesomeDialogFragment();
        f.setArguments(new Bundle(0));
        return f;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.YourStyle)
                .setView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_done, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, null)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
    }
}
```

You need to override `onCreateDialog()` instead. In this way you can apply your custom style.

You can call your fragment in the following way:

```
AwesomeDialogFragment.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "your_tag");
```

Comment: I'm not creating a AlertDialog. I have 5 different DialogFragments, some with edittext and others with just buttons and textviews. But all of them shall have the same style as specified in style.xml

Comment: It doesn't matter. It will be the same. You can provide your own custom layout with the `setView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try you to put the

`setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.ArionDialogFragment)`

code inside the onCreate() method in the PopUP class.

```java
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME,R.style.ArionDialogFragment); 
}
```

This will let the dialog to apply correctly the style that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //the following line has to be placed before the inflater gets created
    getContext().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.ArionDialogFragment, true);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_connectsensor, container, false);

    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourDialogFragment : DialogFragment()   
override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.YourStyleDialog
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality. In order to optimize it you should at least add some explanation to your answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29208254)